# JQuery input number spinner changing ALL spinners on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, spinner

First of all, Hi everyone! 
I do not know JQuery and I have just started learning Javascript. So below you will see a code that I took and used somewhere else on my website but it is not working as it should work. 
The problem is that the code I have used, was meant to have just one number spinner on a page but I need to have multiple of them.

Code:

```
<script>
jQuery(
    function( $ ) {
        if ( typeof js_local_vars.woocommerce_23 !== 'undefined' ) {
            var $testProp = $( 'div.quantity:not(.buttons_added), td.quantity:not(.buttons_added)' ).find( 'AddnQty' );
            if ( $testProp && $testProp.prop( 'type' ) != 'date' ) {
                // Quantity buttons
                $( 'div.quantity:not(.buttons_added), td.quantity:not(.buttons_added)' ).addClass( 'buttons_added' ).append( '<input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />' ).prepend( '<input type="button" value="-" class="minus" />' );

                // Target quantity inputs on product pages
                $( 'input.AddnQty:not(.product-quantity input.AddnQty)' ).each(
                    function() {

                        var min = parseFloat( $( this ).attr( 'min' ) );

                        if ( min && min > 0 && parseFloat( $( this ).val() ) < min ) {
                            $( this ).val( min );
                        }
                    }
                );

                $( document ).on(
                    'click', '.plus, .minus', function() {

                        // Get values
                        var $AddnQty = $( this ).closest( '.quantity' ).find( '.AddnQty' ),
                            currentVal = parseFloat( $AddnQty.val() ),
                            max = parseFloat( $AddnQty.attr( 'max' ) ),
                            min = parseFloat( $AddnQty.attr( 'min' ) ),
                            step = $AddnQty.attr( 'step' );

                        // Format values
                        if ( !currentVal || currentVal === '' || currentVal === 'NaN' ) currentVal = 0;
                        if ( max === '' || max === 'NaN' ) max = '';
                        if ( min === '' || min === 'NaN' ) min = 0;
                        if ( step === 'any' || step === '' || step === undefined || parseFloat( step ) === 'NaN' ) step = 1;

                        // Change the value
                        if ( $( this ).is( '.plus' ) ) {

                            if ( max && ( max == currentVal || currentVal > max ) ) {
                                $AddnQty.val( max );
                            } else {
                                $AddnQty.val( currentVal + parseFloat( step ) );
                            }

                        } else {

                            if ( min && ( min == currentVal || currentVal < min ) ) {
                                $AddnQty.val( min );
                            } else if ( currentVal > 0 ) {
                                $AddnQty.val( currentVal - parseFloat( step ) );
                            }

                        }

                        // Trigger change event
                        $AddnQty.trigger( 'change' );
                    }
                );
            }
        }

    }
);
</script>
```

It is PHP, not HTML. Here is code:

```
 <div class="quantity">
        <input type="number" autocomplete="off" step="" 
class="input-text addon addon-input_multiplier AddnQty text" 
data-price="<?php echo get_product_addon_price_for_display( $option['price'] ); ?>" 
name="<?php echo $addon_key ?>[<?php echo $option_key; ?>]" 
title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'AddnQty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" 
value="<?php echo ( esc_attr( $current_value ) == '' ? $option['min'] : esc_attr( $current_value ) ); ?>" 
</div>
```

I understand that the problem is AddnQty variable but I do not have a clue how to rewrite this code.

Also, I tried using different input number spinners but problem with it was that they changed the value just 'visually' but in fact it wasn't changing. Because the number inside this input had to change the global number(price of a product)(other script) but it didn't change. 
So  initial global number = 1000,  the number spinner  1   global price = 1000 + 1 x some number.

So if it is easier to say how to make script "update" the value inside input, it would be great.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is the HTML code? need to see the html code to be able to reproduce the problem, before we can attempt to solve it. Better is if you can create a JSfiddle of it.

Comment: @NawedKhan Sorry! I edited the question. But here is website, you will see what I mean : http://www.finarium.com/product/belize/  on the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle where the code is working fine on multiple inputs.

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/6pscv2rg/)

```
$(function() {

var $testProp = $('div.quantity:not(.buttons_added), td.quantity:not(.buttons_added)').find('.AddnQty');
if ($testProp && $testProp.prop('type') != 'date') {
  // Quantity buttons
  $('div.quantity:not(.buttons_added), td.quantity:not(.buttons_added)').addClass('buttons_added').append('<input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />').prepend('<input type="button" value="-" class="minus" />');

  // Target quantity inputs on product pages
  $('input.AddnQty:not(.product-quantity input.AddnQty)').each(
    function() {

      var min = parseFloat($(this).attr('min'));

      if (min && min > 0 && parseFloat($(this).val()) < min) {
        $(this).val(min);
      }
    }
  );

  $(document).on(
    'click', '.plus, .minus',
    function() {

      // Get values
      var $AddnQty = $(this).closest('.quantity').find('.AddnQty'),
        currentVal = parseFloat($AddnQty.val()),
        max = parseFloat($AddnQty.attr('max')),
        min = parseFloat($AddnQty.attr('min')),
        step = $AddnQty.attr('step');

      // Format values
      if (!currentVal || currentVal === '' || currentVal === 'NaN') currentVal = 0;
      if (max === '' || max === 'NaN') max = '';
      if (min === '' || min === 'NaN') min = 0;
      if (step === 'any' || step === '' || step === undefined || parseFloat(step) === 'NaN') step = 1;

      // Change the value
      if ($(this).is('.plus')) {

        if (max && (max == currentVal || currentVal > max)) {
          $AddnQty.val(max);
        } else {
          $AddnQty.val(currentVal + parseFloat(step));
        }
      } else {

        if (min && (min == currentVal || currentVal < min)) {
          $AddnQty.val(min);
        } else if (currentVal > 0) {
          $AddnQty.val(currentVal - parseFloat(step));
        }
      }

      // Trigger change event
      $AddnQty.trigger('change');
    }
  );
}
```

});

Comment: Much thanks for your time!
Finally, I found an answer. It wasn't problem with the code. The problem was that I put the code in php file, which was loading for each number input. So there were same code many times.